# NSScrollView Scroll background visible when use USB mouse

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, osx-yosemite, xcode6.1, nsscrollview

I have an NSScrollView it works fine but when I use USB mouse instead of magic mouse the scrollers become visible and their background colour change to white.
I tried to set the scrollers style, but nothing changed.

My os is Yosemite 10.10.2
My Xcode version is 6.1.1

Any idea how can i set the scroller background transparent ?

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11253949/scroller-background-not-transparent-in-nsscrollview

Comment: And "Overlay Scrollbars" section in [What's New in OS X Lion v10.7](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/MacOSX/WhatsNewInOSX/Articles/MacOSX10_7.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010355-SW39)